# Simulte error: LteChannelControl not found

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to run simulte with omnet 5.0 and inet 3.4. I build in with terminal.
When i try to run tutorial simulation via
Right-clicking on simulations/tutorial/omnetpp.ini and "Run as Omnet simulation", it gives me following error

Error in module (omnetpp::cModule) SingleCell (id=1) during network setup:Class "LteChannelControl" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module/Define_Channel().

Now I have also checked LteChannelControl class .cc and it infact has the Define_Module(LteChannelControl) inside.

If you have any idea how to resolve this, it will be eppreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by running simulations via terminal. It appears that using Omnet gui for simulte gives alot of problems. Simulte wants to be used via terminal or cmd instead.